# Mean centering before PCA

Tags: python, data-analysis, pca, centering

I am unsure if this kind of question (related to PCA) is acceptable here or not.

However, it is suggested to do MEAN CENTER before PCA, as known. In fact, I have 2 different classes (**Each different class has different participants.**). My aim is to distinguish and classify those 2 classes. Still, I am not sure about MEAN CENTER that should be applied to the whole data set, or to each class.

Is it better to make it separately? (if it is, should PREPROCESSING STEPS also be separately as well?) or does it not make any sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PCA is just a rotation, optionally accompanied with a projection onto a lower-dimensional space. It finds axes of maximal variance (which happen to be the principal axes of inertia of your point cloud) and then rotates the dataset to align those axes with your coordinate's system. You get to decide how many such axes you'd like to retain, which means the rotation is then followed by projection onto the first `k` axes of greatest variance, with `k` the dimensionality of the representation space you'll have chosen.

With this in mind, again like for calculating axes of inertia, you could decide to look for such axes through the center of mass of your cloud (the mean), or through any arbitrary origin of choice. In the former case, you would mean-center your data, and in the latter you may translate the data to any arbitrary point, with the result being to diminish the importance of the intrinsic cloud shape itself and increase the importance of the distance between the center of mass and the arbitrary point. Thus, in practice, **you would almost always center your data**.

You may also want to **standardize** your data (center and divide by standard deviation so as to make variance 1 on each coordinate), or even [whiten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitening_transformation) your data.

In any case, **you will want to apply the same transformations to the entire dataset, not class by class**. If you were to apply the transformation class by class, whatever distance exists between the centers of gravity of each would be reduced to 0, and you would likely observe a collapsed representation with the two classes as overlapping. This may be interesting if you want to observe the intrinsic shape of each class, but then you would also apply PCA separately for each class.

Please note that PCA *may* make it easier for you to **visualize** the two classes (without guarantees, if the data are truly n-dimensional without much of a lower-dimensional embedding). But **in no circumstances would it make it easier to *discriminate* between the two**. If anything, PCA will reduce how discriminable your classes are, and it is often the case that the projection will intermingle classes (increase ambiguity) that are otherwise quite distinct and e.g. separable with a simple hyper-surface.

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative explanation. One thing will be mentioned again: so, it means that even though the classes (in this case, healthy and cancer groups) have their own population/patients, we have to do mean-centring to the whole dataset, but not to each class? Is it not the reason why we should do mean-centring for each class just because the gravity of each is already different?

Comment: As I said, it all depends on what you want to do with PCA. It is really just a visualization tool to help interpret your dataset. If you are interested in the shape of each class (independent of their inter-relation), then mean-center (and optionally standardize) each class separately, but then also use PCA independently on each. If you'd like to visualize the two classes and how they relate to one another, then process (mean, std, PCA) the whole dataset together. If you'd like to classify, then _do not use PCA at all_, and instead train a classifier.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice explanation and your precious time!

Answer (score 1):

PCA is more or less per definition a SVD with centering of the data.

Depending on the implementation (if you use a PCA from a library) the centering is applied automatically e.g. sklearn - because as said it has to be centered by definition.
So for sklearn you do not need this preprocessing step and in general you apply it over your whole data.

PCA is unsupervised can be used to find a representation that is more meaningful and representative for you classes *afterwards*. So you need all your samples in the same feature space via the same PCA.

---

In short: You do the PCA once and over your whole (training) data and must be center over your whole (traning) data. Libraries like sklarn do the centering automatically.

Comment: Thank you for this valuable comment. One thing more; I have heard that centring should be done for each class because each class is representative for its own population. Therefore, there is another term called "class centre" which takes the mean of each class and subtracts the means from each observation. However, I am not exactly sure.

Comment: To be more specific and to give an example, I have 2 different classes; Healthy and Cancer. Each class has their own population/observation.

Comment: There are two things that come to my mind. a) if you want to classify/project an unknown sample and you have two different means, which one would you apply? a.2) At least for PCA you can only apply one globaly, like you said could substract both but then do SVD from the not globaly centered data. I cannot say how the results will be. b) PCA has one "problem" that it is linear some features e.g. in health data might be non-linear corelated and can not be detected as such by PCA. -> it could make sense have two PCAs and apply each and check where the unknown sample fits better. Has to be tested.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very supportive. For the question, I have come to this conclusion from one of the commercial software which allows you to do different types of centring. In this link, https://wiki.eigenvector.com/index.php?title=Classcentroid, they give detailed info about class centring. As an option, they use CLASS CENTROID CENTERING, which basically helps you to get the mean of the means of two classes. Seems intriguing!

Answer (score 0):

The k neareast neighbor will help you distinquish between the two classes.  Also try tsne to visualize data classes using higher dimensions.

```
def pca_classifier(X, y, n_components=2, n_neighbors=1):
    """
    X: numpy array of shape (n_samples, n_features)
    y: numpy array of shape (n_samples, )
    n_components: int, number of components to keep
    n_neighbors: int, number of neighbors to use in the knn classifier
    """
    # 1. PCA
    pca = PCA(n_components=n_components)
    X_pca = pca.fit_transform(X)
    
    # 2. KNN
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=n_neighbors)
    knn.fit(X_pca, y)
    
    # 3. plot
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    plt.scatter(X_pca[:, 0], X_pca[:, 1], c=y, cmap=plt.cm.Set1, edgecolor='k')
    plt.xlabel('PC1')
    plt.ylabel('PC2')
    plt.title('PCA')
    plt.show()
    
    return knn
```